# Validation of a custom directive (I want to make it required) in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a problem with validating a custom directive in a form with AngularJS. The directive that I created is called **switcher**, and it's put inside a form, ChoixController form.

The code is like this :

```
    <form id="choixContext"  name="choixContext" ng-submit="choixController.save(choixContext)">
<label for="choixDevis">Choice of Devis </label>
 <switcher name="choixDevis" id="choixDevis" grid="'grid-3-small-3-tiny-1'" values="choixContextContrat" model="codeChoix"/>
    <div class="msg-error-input"
         ng-if="!codeChoix"
         ng-messages="choixContext['codeChoix'].$error"
         role="alert">
        <div class="icon icon-mobile-attention-carre" ng-message="required">
            Erreur !
        </div>
    </div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

How can I do this ? I want the directive to be required. The user has to choose to click on the directive before submitting.

Here's the HTML code of the directive :

```
<div class="switcher {{grid}}" ng-cloak>
    <label class="switch {{item.class}}"
         data-ng-repeat="item in values">
        <input name="{{name}}" type="radio" value="{{item.code}}" ng-model="$parent.model">
        <span class="switch-data">
            <span class="icon {{item.icon}}" data-ng-if="item.icon"></span>
            <span class="switcher-libelle" data-ng-bind-html="item.libelle"></span>
        </span>
    </label>
    <label class="switch switch-other" data-ng-if="otherRadio">
        <input id="{{otherRadioId}}" name="{{name}}" type="radio" value="{{otherRadioValue}}" ng-model="$parent.model">
        <span class="switch-data" data-ng-bind-html="otherRadioLibelle"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way it may not be a good idea to have your customer name on the screen.

Comment: You're right. I edited my post. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

AS far as i know angular form will only add `input` `select` `textarea` to his validity system.

An easy way to get around this is to create an hidden input :

```
<input name="monChoix" type="hidden" ng-model="codeChoix" required />
 <div class="msg-error-input"
     ng-if="!codeChoix"
     ng-messages="choixContext['monChoix'].$error"
     role="alert">
    <div class="icon icon-macif-mobile-attention-carre" ng-message="required">
        Erreur !
    </div>
</div>
```

Also note that it's the input's name that must match in your ng-messages not the variable name where you store the value. THis is why i renamed it to `monChoix` so you'll see the link better.

Comment: Then you have to add the required to the input in the directive. If you don't want to modify their code you can use the $decorator to change the template.

Comment: a little demo here : http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/. Check the source code of your directive. if the template is define as `template` var of the directive, you just want to change the $decorator.template value to add the required to the input. For more information we'll need the directive declaration of the switcher.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is use ng-message. And next you need do this on `<switcher />`:

- change model for ng-model
- add attribute required

Next, you need add ng-messages:

```
<div ng-messages="choixContext.choixDevis.$error" role="alert">
  <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
</div>
```

For more information:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

If you need more help, please, make a plunker.

Comment: I added the HTML code of the directive..I don't know if this can help you